# How to reference 'this' in a lambda used with a LUA script

Tags: c++, lua

I'm trying to add the LUA API to my C++ program, and I'm attempting to allow the script to draw to my GUI. So far, I have this for my lambda function:

```
auto addToDrawList = [](lua_State* L) -> int
{
    int DrawType = (int)lua_tonumber(L, -2);
    std::string Label = (std::string)lua_tostring(L, -1);

    bool found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i <= DrawList.size(); i++)
    {
        if (DrawList[i].Active == false && !found)
        {
            switch (DrawType)
            {
            case(0):
                break;
            case(1):
                DrawList[i].Active = true;
                DrawList[i].DrawType = Type::TextBox;
                DrawList[i].Label = Label;
                break;
            }
            found = true;
        }
    }

    return 0;
};
```

This as my LUA script being run:

```
const char* LUA_FILE = R"(
    addToDrawList(1, "Test")
)";
```

This is how I'm pushing my function to the LUA stack:

```
lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();

lua_newtable(L);
int uiTableInd = lua_gettop(L);
lua_pushvalue(L, uiTableInd);
lua_setglobal(L, "Ui");

lua_pushcfunction(L, addToDrawList);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "addToDrawList");
```

The problem is within my first script, as it can't get to the 'DrawList' array as its inside of `this`.

So, to resolve it, I tried to add `this` to the lambda's capture list by doing this:

```
auto addToDrawList = [this](lua_State* L) -> int
```

Which appeared to work and resolve the error, but then I had an issue with the last script:

```
lua_pushcfunction(L, addToDrawList);
```

[image: Error]

I've been searching the Internet for a fix, but I can't find any.

Comment: `lua_pushcfunction` is a C function, it only knows about C data-types like plain simple function pointers. A captureless lambda can be converted into a plain simple function pointer, but when you add captures it's no longer possible.

Comment: On a side note, `i <= DrawList.size()` will go out of bounds of the `DrawList`. You need to use `<` instead.

Comment: thanks so much Remy i always used to -1 instead of < thanks thats so obvious when i think about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lua_pushcfunction()` takes a C-style function pointer.  A *capture-less* lambda can be converted to such a function pointer, but a *capturing* lambda cannot.

Use [`lua_pushcclosure()`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_pushcclosure)<sup>1</sup> instead.  It will allow you to associate user-defined values (known as [upvalues](https://www.lua.org/pil/27.3.3.html)) with the C function, such as your `this` pointer, or just a pointer to `DrawList`, etc.

> When a C function is created, it is possible to associate some values with it, thus creating a C closure (see [§3.4](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#3.4)); **these values are then accessible to the function whenever it is called**. To associate values with a C function, first these values should be pushed onto the stack (when there are multiple values, the first value is pushed first). Then `lua_pushcclosure` is called to create and push the C function onto the stack, with the argument `n` telling how many values should be associated with the function. `lua_pushcclosure` also pops these values from the stack.

<sup>1: `lua_pushcfunction()` is just a wrapper for `lua_pushcclosure()` with 0 upvalues defined.</sup>

For example:

```cpp
auto addToDrawList = [](lua_State* L) -> int
{
    const MyClassType *pThis = (const MyClassType*) lua_topointer(L, lua_upvalueindex(1));

    // use pThis->DrawList as needed...

    return 0;
};

...

lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
...
//lua_pushcfunction(L, addToDrawList);
lua_pushlightuserdata(L, this);
lua_pushcclosure(L, addToDrawList, 1);
...
```

Comment: Im assuing i have to increment the stack index for my lua_tonumber and tostring as pushing light user data adds it to the stack  correct?

Comment: @ConnorBilham I have no clue, as I don't use LUA myself, I'm just referring to what the LUA documentation explains. You will have to try it for yourself and see what happens.

Comment: So far its compiling without an issue will get back to you on if it worked or not in a bit

Comment: turns out it isnt added directly to the stack so i spent a while scratching my head for an assumption so i reverted it back to 2, 1 and it worked perfectly, thanks for your help